# A question about Comparison Principle in Nonlinear Systems?

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions, adaptive-control

**A question about Comparison Principle**

For a general system, we have
$$
V=x^{2}+y^{2}
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$ are two independent states, and $V$ is a Lyapunov function. There are two cases: Case 1 is very common, based which I formulate the question in Case 2 .

Case 1. If
$$
\dot{V} \leqslant-K\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)+\beta
$$
holds for $K>0$ and $\beta>0$, we have
$$
\dot{V} \leqslant-K V+\beta
$$
then, according to Comparison Principle,
$$
\limsup _{t \rightarrow \infty} V=\limsup _{t \rightarrow \infty}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right) \leqslant \frac{\beta}{K}
$$
Case 2. If
$$
\dot{V} \leqslant-K\left(x^{2}+100 y^{2}\right)+\beta
$$
holds for $K>0$ and $\beta>0$, will we have
$$
\limsup _{t \rightarrow \infty}\left(x^{2}+100 y^{2}\right) \leqslant \frac{\beta}{K} ?
$$

Comment: No, in the second case, you can only conclude the same thing as in the first case, since we have that $\dot{V} \leqslant-K\left(x^{2}+100 y^{2}\right)+\beta\le -K\left(x^{2}+ y^{2}\right)+\beta=-KV+\beta$.

Comment: @KBS Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about it is that in case 1, you define a new variable $Y$ such that
$$Y' = -K Y + \beta.$$
And you assume $Y(0) = V(0)$ and $Y'\geq V'$. Then, $Y(t) \geq V(t)$ for all $t\ge 0$.

Then, by $Y'$, you have that the limit as $t\rightarrow \infty$ for $Y(t)$ approaches $\beta/K$ (from below or above dependent on the initial $Y(0)$. That's one way to conclude that $\limsup_{t\rightarrow\infty} V \leq \beta/K$.

In case 2, you don't need the whole part because you are only concern with
$$Y' = -K(x^2 + 100y^2) + \beta$$
where it's implicitly assumed that $Y = x^2 + 100y^2$. Then your conclusion follows.  $V$ just coincidentally happens to be always smaller or equal to $Y$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But in case 2, if $Y=x^2+y^2$, what can we obtained except for $\limsup_{t\rightarrow \infty}x^2+y^2 \leqslant \frac{\beta}{K}$?

Comment: @PengPeng It depends on what you want. If $Y = x^2 + y^2$ and assume that $Y' = -K(x^2 + 100y^2) + \beta$, then $Y' \leq -K(x^2 + y^2) + \beta = -KY + \beta$, which gives you that conclusion. Is there a specific conclusion that you want to obtain?

Comment: @Paichu Clearly, the conclusion that the OP is making in the second case is not correct.

Comment: @KBS Obviously.

Comment: @Paichu Thanks. I want $\limsup _{t \rightarrow \infty}\left(x^{2}+100 y^{2}\right) \leqslant \frac{\beta}{K}$ when $Y=x^2+y^2$. Maybe is is impossible.

Comment: @PengPeng there's not enough constrains for that result.

Comment: @Paichu OK, I understand your answer. Thank you very much.